# how calabash query control which doesn't have ID or name

Tags: calabash

I am new comer to `calabash`, I want to click the highlighted element, but don't know how to get that.

**Element Structure Screen:**

[image: Element Structure Screen]

Comment: Does it have an id? If so use that one. If it does not then give it an id and use it then :) You could click based on coordinates but that is not a good solution. You could also do a query for all images and click the correct index of that result but that is also not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things that you can query on to find an element.  ID's are the least brittle in my opinion, and it'll be better to get an ID added to the element than to work around it not being there.

However, if there that isn't an option, you can chain together queries to find the element relative to an element that does have an ID or some text.

```
query("* id:'Something' ImageView")
query("* id:'SomehthingElse' * ImageView")
```

By default the direction the queries work is to look at the descendants of an element, but you can look at parents too if that's necessary https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/05-Query-Syntax#direction

You can also find elements using their class and an index number though for something as common as an ImageView that probably isn't a good idea as it'll be very likely to break.

```
query('ImageView index:2')
```